# Changing the radio button value when retrieving from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a two radio buttons on my form which is named as "status"and the values are 1 and 0. So when I submit the form and checked one of the radio buttons it's stored on the database. The problem is when I retrieve the data from database included the status column name, I wanted it to be set as "active" or "inactive".

View:

```
 <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Date Registered</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach($users as $key => $value) {?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value['firstname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['lastname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['status']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['datereg']; ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('main/showUser/'.$value['id']); ?>">
            <i class="material-icons" title="Click to update">mode_edit</i></a> |
            <a href="" class="remove"><i class="material-icons" title="Click to remove">
            delete</i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Controller:

```
  public function usersPage() {
    $data['users'] = $this->user->getUsers();
    $this->load->view('user_page' , $data);
  }
```

Model:

```
public function getUsers() {
    $this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, date_registered, status');
    $this->db->from('auth_users');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result();

      foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = array(
      'id'  => $value->id,
      'firstname' => $value->first_name,
      'lastname' => $value->last_name,
      'datereg' => $value->date_registered,
      'email' => $value->email,
        'status' => $value->status
      );
    }
    return $data;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($users as $key => $value) 
{
    // Write Here Like This.
    $status=$value['status'] == 1 ?'active':'inactive';
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $value['firstname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $status; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['datereg']; ?></td>
    <td>
```

Answer (score 3):

easiest way, put this in your Model:

```
'status' => $value->status ? 'active' : 'inactive'
```